# Are WSDLs always public?

Tags: wsdl

I am a newbie in WebServices. I wonder if all WSDLs are public? Aren't there any WSDLs that are kept after a login process like in OWASP's WebGoat project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is the contract definition for your web service.  It is used to generate a proxy for your client so it can interface with the service.  If you want a "private" web service, you will still need the WSDL to create your proxy classes during development, but then you can disable the ability to access the WSDL so that it cannot be used from your production web service.